# log4net configuration changes at random

Tags: c#, log4net

I have the configuration for log4net in the xml file. This includes a file appender with a default file path.
At startup I get from backend a new file path that I change in configuration.

Now it happens that from time to time the log messages end up in the default file. Usually after several hours of uptime and for several hours, then the path switches back again.

There is no program restart and no other change of the appender.

Comment: Do you initialize the configuration with `ConfigureAndWatch`? If so, an obvious candidate for trouble is the configuration file itself. Failing that, [enable internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) to see when and how the configuration changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you read the configuration from multiple places, or something is overriding your configuration file. Enable internal debugging to see what is happening in the log4net its logs.